# How to add decorator with textblock programmatically to a canvas?

Tags: wpf, xaml, decorator

I'm following a code sample that has this xaml, but how can I construct this programmatically and add it to a canvas?

```
<custom:BalloonDecorator Background="{StaticResource MessageOutBackground}" PointerLength="10"
CornerRadius="5" Margin="10,0,0,0"
HorizontalAlignment="left">
<Border Background="{StaticResource Hilight}" CornerRadius="5">
<Border Background="{StaticResource HilightBottom}"
CornerRadius="5">
<TextBlock Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Border>
</Border>
</custom:BalloonDecorator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a resource of the window (or something else):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <custom:BalloonDecorator x:Key="MyDecorator" Background="{StaticResource MessageOutBackground}" PointerLength="10"
    ...
    </custom:BalloonDecorator>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then get it in code like this:

```
BalloonDecorator myDecorator = FindResource("MyDecorator") as BalloonDecorator;
```

Comment: But how can I decorate my TextBlock programmatically?  Something like myTextBlock.style = myDecorator; ?

Comment: No, just search the internets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.aspx (You should probably define a custom usercontrol for that)